# Select rows and sort them values and add result as new string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello how can i simplify this code, i take 5 rows a need them as sorted string i new column:

`nba_data['lineup']` is data frame and 'lineup' is last column

````
nba_data['lineup'] = 0
for i in range(len(nba_data.index)):
    single_lineup = []
    df_single_lineup = nba_data.iloc[i, 59:64]
    single_lineup = df_single_lineup.values.tolist()
    single_lineup.sort()
    nba_data.iloc[i, -1] = str(single_lineup[0]) + '_' + str(single_lineup[1]) + '_' + str(single_lineup[2]) + '_' + \
                        str(single_lineup[3]) + '_' + str(single_lineup[4])```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
np.random.seed(4)
nba_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,1000, 25).reshape(5,5))
```

nba_data:

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  123  175  440  710  898
1  361  600  457  819  394
2   59  765  872  110  607
3  824  952  314  873  677
4  947   45  295  127  565
```

You used 5 columns `59:64`, since i created my own data here, i used 2 column `2:4`

The actual code is just one line

```
nba_data['new_column'] = nba_data.apply(lambda x:"_".join(sorted(x.iloc[2:4].astype(str).to_list())) , axis=1)
```

nba_data:

```
     0    1    2    3    4 new_column
0  123  175  440  710  898    440_710
1  361  600  457  819  394    457_819
2   59  765  872  110  607    110_872
3  824  952  314  873  677    314_873
4  947   45  295  127  565    127_295
```